# file_get_contents и url без протокола

Tags: php, http, https, file-get-contents

На вход `file_get_contents` подается урл на файл без протокола. Например `//example.com/file.txt`. Но он не хочет жрать такой урл и возвращает false. Можно ли что-то с этим сделать? Может тогда есть какая-то функция которая обработает урл и добавит ему протокол? Я имею ввиду не просто `'http:' + $url`, а наилучший протокол - как это делает браузер. Если есть https - то пусть будет https, если нет то http. Ведь именно поэтому у урла и убран протокол...

P.S. Правда заранее не известно будет подан урл или реальный путь...

Comment: file_get_contents не принимает https

Comment: @RuslanMirzapulatov чепуха - [принимает](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/how-to-get-file-get-contents-to-work-with-https)

Comment: А, да, точно, настроить нужно. извиняюсь

Comment: В php из коробки такого нет. Видимо вам в сторону написания собственной функции, которая ткнётся по http или https и подберёт url. По логике стоит сначала запросить https и если ответ будет - сразу и использовать его, а если нет - тестировать http.

Comment: __"а наилучший протокол - как это делает браузер"__ браузер не подбирает наилучший протокол. Если на сайте есть редирект http->https, то будет переход. Если нет редиректа, то что откроете, то и отобразится

Comment: @AK что-то не верится... Даже хром это умеет, а пхп нет?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov ок, может и так. Но факт остается фактом - `file_get_contents` не принимает ссылки без протокола.

Comment: @DarkByte хром тоже не принимает ссылки без протокола. выставляется протокол по умолчанию или берется из рефёрера. если в адресной строке вбить //ya.ru/ - будет file:///ya.ru/ так как нет рефёрера...

Comment: @eri нет. Будет https://ya.ru. Ты вообще пробовал сам что сказал?)

Comment: Правильно, без протокола он считает, что это файл на диске

Comment: тс забанен на месяц, расходимся )

Comment: не поленюсь и хром поставлю, 2 минуты..

Comment: https://pp.userapi.com/c850032/v850032739/79e0a/LN3X-cmVdEA.jpg - вот переходит на file://. ПС

у нового хрома наконец красивые вкладочки!!! 15 лет наверное прошло.

Answer (score 2):

`//example.com/file.txt` - это не "выбор наилучшего протокола". Это protocol relative url.

Protocol Relative означает "тот же протокол, что у текущей страницы".

Простая аналогия - просто relative url вида `/file.txt` означает "тот же протокол, хост и порт, что у текущей страницы". Нельзя отдать `file_get_contents` ссылку вида `/file.txt` и ожидать, что метод сам угадает наилучший хост.

То же самое с Protocol Relative - нельзя отдать `//example.com/file.txt`и ожидать что `file_get_contents` угадает протокол.

Answer (score 0):

> *Если есть https - то пусть будет https, если нет то http.*

```
$str = 'https://example.com/file.txt';
echo get_protocol($str) . "\n"; # https://example.com/file.txt

$str = 'http://example.com/file.txt';
echo get_protocol($str) . "\n"; # http://example.com/file.txt

$str = '//example.com/file.txt';
echo get_protocol($str) . "\n"; # http://example.com/file.txt


function get_protocol($str) {
    if (preg_match('~^//\S+~', $str, $url)) {
        $str = "http:$url[0]";
    }

    return $str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents('http:' . $url)`

лучше работайте по http, если нет ценной информаций, которую могу воровать по сети

http быстрее https

а ещё лучше используйте curl, либо можете отправить ping сначало по одному протоколу, и после по другому, чтобы узнать какой будет работать
можно ещё такую проверку сделать:

```
$reg_exUrl = "/(?i)\b((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/";

if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $string, $url)) {

        if(strpos( $url[0], ":" ) === false){
            $link = 'https://'.$url[0];
        }else{
            $link = $url[0];
        }
        $res = file_get_contents($link);

}
```